# How to render two separate models on same page?

Tags: python, django

I am making a post-comment web app. On the home page, various posts are displayed along with an "Answer/Comment" button. When clicked on it, I need to show the contents of the post being answered along with the comment form. The posts and comments are separate models.

So far I have scanned the web for methods to display two separate models on same page. But here, I need to render the post content using "GET" and it's pk and a form to submit comment which is a "POST" method.

This is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
pid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
content = RichTextUploadingField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog-home')#, kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
answer = RichTextUploadingField()
comment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


def __str__(self):
    return self.answer


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog-home')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My views.py is something like this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Comment
fields = ['answer']

def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

The two urls- one for post detail view and for comment create view are as below:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment-create')
```

The template for comment_form is as below:

```html
% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block extrahead %}
<script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/';</script>
{{ block.super }}
{% block detail %}
{% include "blog/post_detail.html" with pid="object.post_id" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block answer %}

 <div class="content-section">
  <form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
     Answer</legend>
     {{form.media}}
     {{form|crispy}}
   </fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info", type="submit">Submit
    </button>
   </div>
  </form> 
 </div>
{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

On clicking the answer button, I expect both of the above urls to run and render the post-detail page on the upper half and comment create view on the lower half of a single page. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you expect two URLs to 'run'? Only the URL for the page you are actually on will be called.

Comment: I want a template where the user can read through the content of the post that they are commenting on. I am a novice to coding, so forgive me if I asked the wrong question.